Wierd flickering on screen with Kubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat) Dev Build
I am testing out Kubuntu 24.04 on my Acer Aspire A515-51. (Neofetch output below).
Neofetch output
I am getting some occasional weird screen flickering when scrolling or navigating web pages. I am confused on what to next, as I have already updated my OS. This also only seems to happen when the charger is plugged in, or if I am using a power plan. Just wondering if there is a way to fix it or not. Thanks!

Ubuntu 24.04 (noble) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu noble and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu noble you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues, and please note the release is still in beta
